# PHP exec does not execute the exe file

Tags: python, php, exec

I've search almost everywhere in the web for answers yet none worked. Please help me with this.

I made a simple python script that exports data into a text file. Then, I compiled it to exe. Using a php code, my plan is to execute the script via the exec() PHP function when clicking the export button. The script should run and prompt the user if the export is successful. However, if I test the export button, the page will only load forever. It will not run the exe file. I tried creating a bat file so instead of connecting directly to exe, the php will execute the bat file itself. Unfortunately, it does not also run the bat file. If I manually start the bat, it does the job.

```
/** Code for the exe **/
exec("dist/export.exe");

/** Code for bat **/
exec("exec_export.bat");

/** Bat file contents **/
cd dist\
START export.exe
```

The exe is in the dist folder which is the sub folder of the same folder where the export php file is kept. Using the is_executable PHP function, I can firmly confirm that the issue is not about the location of the exe since it returns true if I run the code. If I use cmd to START the export exe, it runs successfully. So the question here is, what am I missing? Is there some configuration in the php.ini that I need to do to allow php to run exe file? Any configuration in the WAMPP? Please help me.

Comment: Why don't you pass and output variable and and return code variable and see what the `exec` outputs when it tries to run the program? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @bassxzero okay. I'll try that!

Comment: [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)

Comment: @mario I did the configurations in the php.ini. It runs but the site is still forever loading even though the exe has completed it's task

Comment: @bassxzero the link that mario gave, solved the problem partially. Please read my reply to mario